# My products are showing "not in stock" and I don't know why

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, production

If I list the item as "out of stock" the label changes to red and says `"OUT OF STOCK"` on the product. If I set it as "in stock" the product says `"Availability: not in Stock"`

I can even set a specific quantity and manage stockkeeping and it still says `"Availability: not in Stock"`

I don't know what the difference between "not in stock" and "out of stock" is but the latter is bold, red and clearly a problem. The "not in stock" label shows up no matter what and you can still buy a product.

Where is this property kept? What is it tracking and how do I get this to go away?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the difference is "Not in stock" relates to products that can be [backordered](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/managing-products/#section-25), and "Out of stock" means sold out, with no plans for getting more.

If you are not managing inventory (that is, you manually set a product to Out of Stock when it sells out), then you need to ensure that "Manage stock?" is unchecked on all products (and product variations).

If you've used a CSV Import/Export tool, sometimes stock levels that should be `NULL` get set to zero, and that's what causes the issue. I hope this helps!